# JOOQ Duplicate a record but to another table

Tags: jooq

Let's say I have two tables with almost entirely similar fields: "Data" and "DataDraft".

How can I read a specific record from "Data" and write it to "DataDraft" without copying every field one by one into a new DataDraftRecord object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`record.into(Table)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record.html#into(org.jooq.Table)) can do this for you:

```java
DataRecord data = ...
DataDraftRecord dataDraft = data.into(DATA_DRAFT);
```